# i want to make urls

Tags: python, pandas

1.Link is "https://www.xyz.{country}/dp/{asin}"
2.I have to pick two things from csv file which country and asin.
CSV file contains :

```
      Asin     Country
0      1011         de
1      1022         fr
2      1033         de
```

My question :
How can I extract asin and country one by one and make urls like

```
https://www.xyz.{country}/dp/{asin}  -->  https://www.xyz.de/dp/1011
https://www.xyz.{country}/dp/{asin}  -->  https://www.xyz.fr/dp/1022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
lst_url=[]
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    country=df.loc[index,'Country']
    asin=df.loc[index,'Asin']
    url=f"https://www.xyz.{country}/dp/{asin}"
    lst_url.append(url)
```

`lst_url` will contain all the url you want

Answer (score 0):

Filter columns by list `['Country','Asin']`, convert to numpy and in `for` get scalars passed to `f-string`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)

for country, asin in df[['Country','Asin']].to_numpy():
   url=f"https://www.xyz.{country}/dp/{asin}"
   print (url)
   
https://www.xyz.de/dp/1011
https://www.xyz.fr/dp/1022
https://www.xyz.de/dp/1033
```

For list use:

```
L = [f"https://www.xyz.{country}/dp/{asin}" 
        for country, asin in df[['Country','Asin']].to_numpy()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    datas = f.readlines()

for data in datas[1:]:
    asin, country = data.split()
    print(f'https://www.xyz.{country}/dp/{asin}')
```

result:

```sh
https://www.xyz.de/dp/1011
https://www.xyz.fr/dp/1022
https://www.xyz.de/dp/1033
```